# Properties null when using /users but not when using /me/contacts

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When getting contacts from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts` I get all properties for a user, ex:

```
{
  displayName: 'Joe Joeson',
  jobTitle: 'Administrator',
  department: 'HK',
  mobilePhone: '09823987234',
  businessPhones: '8934598743',
  mail: 'joe@mail.com',
}
```

But when I get all users of the organization (with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,jobTitle,department,mobilePhone,businessPhones,mail,userType`) the same contact doesnt get some properties, ex:

```
{
  displayName: 'Joe Joeson',
  jobTitle: null,
  department: null,
  mobilePhone: null,
  businessPhones: null,
  mail: 'joe@mail.com',
}
```

Why? Its the same contact? Or am I missing something? Should I get all contacts from the organization in another way?

I have confirmed that all properties are set in `https://portal.azure.com`

Comment: What permission scopes have you requested?

Comment: Hi! these: `View users' basic profile`,`Sign users in`, `Read user contacts`, `Read all users' basic profiles`, `Sign in and read user profile` and `Read user and shared contacts`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/contacts` and `/users` endpoints return two different entities. A `contact` entity represents an Outlook Contact from the current user's Exchange mailbox whereas the a `user` entity represents an User directory object from the tenant's Active Directory instance.

The reason you're seeing two different results is because you're returning two different entities. The first is the Joe Joeson `contact` from your Outlook/Exchange mailbox and the second is the Joe Joeson `user` from Active Directory.

The reason you're seeing less information from `/users` is due to your requesting the `Read all users' basic profiles` (aka `User.ReadBasic.All`) scope. This scope can only see a limited number of properties from a `user` resource: `displayName`, `givenName`, `surname`, `photo`, and `mail`.

Comment: Oohhhh! I see. Could you tell me what scope I should request? Thank you!!

Comment: `User.Read.All` will give you permission to read the entire property set of a `user`. This will require Admin Consent from a tenant admin before you can use it.

Comment: Hi im having the same issue, I have been granted the delegated permissions for User.Read.All and Im also passing it as a scope in my requests when I request me I get everything but when going through the each object in the get users i dont see the department, initially i was using the User.ReadBasic.All and inwasnt seeing the Job Title aster switching to User.Read.All i could see it but I really need the department... one thinng that caught my attention with this post was the fact ubsaid that the contacts is a separate entity so maybe i should query the contact obj? Whats the scope for that?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur, I get the whole set of users properties but most of them has `null` value. I know that my users have some events in their calendars my there are no events in `/users[someUserId]/events` response. How it can be so?

Comment: One other pitfall to avoid would be to make sure the user who is logged in is not a 'Guest' user for the tenent. For them, even though they bear a token with User.Read.All permission, they still will not be able to query all users from the AD.

Comment: any fix/update for this? I'm getting almost only nulls as well