# Fields return null in Graph API Query

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Querying the graph API returns null for many fields which should not be null, for example jobTitle, userType, createdDateTime, and isAccountEnabled. Why are these fields showing up as null? Is there something that needs to be enabled from the global Azure AD?

How can I get these fields to return with their proper values rather than null?

Comment: Here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47093399/properties-null-when-using-users-but-not-when-using-me-contacts?rq=1) you could refer to.

Answer (score 1):

You need the permission "`Directory.Read.All`" at least.

So that you can read user data in your organization's directory. Otherwise, you will get "`null`" value.

[Microsoft Graph permissions reference - Directory permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#directory-permissions)

Comment: Thanks Joanna, I believe I have this option checked in the Azure Portal for my app. However, the user object is still returned with most fields null. Only  the correct setting? Settings > Required permissions > Enable Access > APPLICATION PERMISSIONS > Read all users' full profiles

Comment: It's a navigation property issue. Most return null by default unless included somehow with a query param I think, I'm still debugging this.

Comment: Any solution/update to this?